# Does SQL Plus can verify if a sql script can be run?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus, static-analysis

In order to improve code quality, I want to verify if SQL*plus can execute an sql script without executing it, like a static analyse of the sql script.
Do you know if SQL*plus can do this ? Or do you know a way to do the same thing.

I know that executing sql scripts from SQL Dev (or another software) isn't the same thing than executing from SQL*plus.

PS: I'm using SQL*plus on Unix.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way to "verify" an sql query without executing it is to use

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your-sql-statement;
```

For more info, see http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Explain_Plan

Comment: That is not what he asked, though.

Comment: Hello LeadingEdger, Thanks for your answer. I don't have a plan table and can't make one :/

Comment: @Funkynene What version of Oracle are you using? It's been a long time since it was necessary to create a plan table. If you're using a very old version it might help to include the version number in the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant at this point :). I use Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

No. The only way to verify scripts is to run them.

Some general thoughts below.

For verifying the paths to scripts referenced within the SQLPlus script, you would need parse the script using bash script for example, looking for commands starting:

`START s1.sql`

`@ s1.sql`

`@@ s1.sql`

Then check the paths form teh script referenced.

SQLPlus understands absolute and relative paths, so teh following are both valid:

`@ ../s1.sql`

`@/tmp/s2.sql`

Also, SQLPlus will default the extension to `.sql`, so if for example you have a script called `s3.sql` you can reference it as either:

`@ s3.sql`

or

`@ s3`

Then you also have the `SQLPATH` environment variable which works in a similar way to the bash `PATH` variable in locating SQL scripts.

Finally, in SQLPlus you can set variables and reference these as file names, e.g.

```
column  col_name  new_value  var_file_name

select col_name  as var_file_name 
from table
where x = y;

spool &&var_file_name
```

The only way to resolve the above would be to run the query. But if this also relies on other variables then you will very quickly end up having to write a full parser for SQLPLus scripts.

You could try an adding elaborate switch to all your scripts that would signal a skip or run but as far as I know there is no `GOTO` or `SKIP` type command which you could use to skip to the end of a script as means of just checking existance.

Comment: Hello TenG,
The current problem I encounter is that SQLPlus does not manage comments very well. I mean, if there an end line comment and a blank line it ignores the sql statement without executing it.
Another problem is to verify if column or whatever object actually exists.
I think I'm gonna do a shell parser myself to make this. I just want to be sure that I have not I simple way to do it. I have to manage with scripts from ten-ish devs and I know all of them don't have good pratices with SQLplus (more often to execute sql statements with SQL dev)

Comment: It sounds like you want to check actual SQL object names as well as checking file path etc,  which means writing a SQL parser as well. I've seen people attempt all sorts of sqlplus and it never fully works. I fear you will spend a lot of time and still find it is not 100% what you need. I think the best way to verify the scripts is to have a test environment that you can rebuild and just test/fix/re-test the scripts until they work, feeding back any advice or comments to the devs.

Comment: I know is the best thing to do but you know how it works on big compagnies :)